# Jumping to the next page in iTextSharp PdfPtable when creating one for a PdfPDocument document

Tags: c#, pdf, report, itext, pdfptable

I'm building up an iTextSharp PdfPTable object that will later be passed to Document.Add() to be populated to a PDF file.

I'm going crazy over trying to figure out how to jump to the next page. Can anyone advise how to format the table and make the text start at what will appear to be the next page once populated to a DPF document ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, had it under "Tags". It's iTextSharp ofcourse.

Comment: Would you show everyone what you've tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found two solutions:

1) Re-creating a new table, triggering `document.NewPage()` and  `document.Add()` every time I had to jump to a new page.

2) Implementing a custom PDFdWriter PageEvent on the `pdfWriter.PageEvent` property.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the solution?